# Netlify error-mixed Content, The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested a HTTP insecure script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cross-domain, netlify, vue-cli

everyone,

I deployed my **vue-cli** website project to **Netlify**, but when I opened the website, got this error: *Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxx.netlify.app/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://yyyy/something.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

Do you guys have similar problems and got any suggestions for me, I appreciate that.

I know that browser has this same-origin security policy to keep user data safe, but my website is a client-side web, I do not have control of the server-side, which means I cannot use CORS. And I send not only GET requests, so JSONP cannot be the solution.

The example case is like: Visitor was at 'https://mywebsite.netlify.app/#/login', after visitor input username and password, click login button, the userAccountLogin function will be called, and send the request:

```js
//-------------in login.js---------------------
import request from 'path here'

const userAccountLogin = ({ account, password }) => {
  return request('/login', 'post', { account, password })
}


// ----------in request.js--------------------
import axios from 'axios'

const baseURL = 'http://apiserver.net/'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  timeout: 5000
})

export default (url, method, submitData) => {
  return instance({
    url,
    method,
    [method.toLowerCase() === 'get' ? 'params' : 'data']: submitData
  })
}
```

The project works well at http://localhost:8080, but needs to solve the cross-origin problem.

Thank you all :)

Comment: const baseURL = 'http://apiserver.net/': You need to use an https api endpoint if the client loads your page over https.

Comment: The error message `the content must be served over HTTPS` is very clear, you should  load static resousces (js/css/image) and send ajax requests over HTTPS if the web page is served over HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you all. 
I understand the error, but I don't have access to the server APIs, so I cannot change what protocols the server-side is using.
In this case, does that mean I have no solution at all ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//-------------in login.js---------------------
import request from 'path here'

const userAccountLogin = ({ account, password }) => {
  return request('/login', 'post', { account, password })
}


// ----------in request.js--------------------
import axios from 'axios'

const baseURL = 'http://apiserver.net/'

const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL,
  timeout: 5000
})

export default (url, method, submitData) => {
  return instance({
    url,
    method,
    [method.toLowerCase() === 'get' ? 'params' : 'data']: submitData
  })
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).